# How to use Acra in release build only?

Tags: acra

I am trying to use http://www.acra.ch/ in my Android app.

How can I make it such that ACRA is used only in the release build and not in the debug builds.

I would have to set dependencies accordingly and have my ApplicationController(extends Application) class be configured accordingly.

How to do both? i.e. How to add a dependency for release only and also how to configure my ApplicationController(extends Application) class be configured?

I should mention that I am using my ApplicationController(extends Application) class for some functionality of the app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just don't initialize Acra in the debug build:

```
if(!BuildConfig.DEBUG) Acra.init(this);
```

If you want to exclude the dependency in debug build, use `releaseCompile`

Comment: Thank you very much. It is times like these when I realize that I am an idiot.